# Bitbake runtime vs build dependency

Tags: dependencies, bitbake

I am having trouble understanding the bitbake recipes. (I have some poorly written I need to modify, I usually would read and understand the whole mechanism but sadly I am on a tight schedule).
Can you please help me understand the difference between RDEPENDS and DEPENDS. I read the reference and I know that they stand for runtime dependency and build dependency respectively, but what is the effect on it in a bitbake recipe?
As far as I understand, if a package A depends on another B, B has to be built and ready to enable A to build. Bitbake isn't related to the runtime, it's only there for building and deploying the packages. So what is the difference?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As you say, bitbake is concerned with building *and deploying* the
packages, and it needs to *deploy* all the packages that are
needed to satisfy *runtime* dependencies on the target system.

If your recipe says that target *T* `DEPENDS` on a target *P*, that tells
bitbake that it must build *P* before *T*, because *T* can't be
*built* without *P*.

If your recipe says that *T* `RDEPENDS` on *P*, that tells
bitbake that it must deploy *P* to the target system if it
deploys *T*, because *T* can't be *used* without *P*.

For example, you can't build `tar` without the C compiler, but
you don't need the C compiler to use `tar`. You can deploy `tar` 
without deploying the C compiler. So that's a `DEPEND`.

On the other hand, you can't use `tar` without the runtime C library.
If `tar` is deployed, the runtime C library must also be deployed. 
So that's an `RDEPEND`.

The bitake technicalities are:

- If *T* `DEPENDS` on *P* then *T*'s `do_configure` task is made to depend
  on *P*'s `do_populate_sysroot` task.
- If *T* `RDEPENDS` on *P* then *T*'s `do_build` task ia made to depend on *P*'s 
  `do_package_write` task.

Comment: Thank you sir! It's clear to me now. About the technicalities you mentioned: Is there a defined order of how a recipe calls those tasks? Are those tasks (do_configure, do_build etc) part of bitbake standard?

Comment: Yes, there is a defined order which is, of course, the right order - although it is possible for you to override or extend any pre-defined behaviour if you want, or to define tasks of your own and insert them in between the predefined ones. See [From Bitbake Hello World to an Image](http://hambedded.org/blog/2012/11/24/from-bitbake-hello-world-to-an-image/)

Comment: Excellent Answer

Comment: This is the best answer I have come across so far!