# Is runtime dependency possible by including a header file?

Tags: c++, dependencies, bitbake

The case is: There is an ipk called A and another called B.
B has a runtime dependency to A (according to bitbake recipe of A)
However, a source file in B has `#include <some_header_in_A>`
This looks like a build dependency to me, but then I cannot explain to myself why the bitbake recipe functions with a runtime dependency.
Any help is appreciated, also a link to some explanatory tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall my [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30847513/1362568).

- If *T* DEPENDS on *P* then *T*'s `do_configure` task is made to depend
  on *P*'s `do_populate_sysroot` task.
- If *T* RDEPENDS on *P* then *T*'s `do_build` task ia made to depend on *P*'s
  `do_package_write` task.

So the fact that your *B* `RDEPENDS` on your *A* means that *A* has already 
passed all stages right through `do_package_write` when `B` is built, including
`do_populate_sysroot`. Therefore any headers that *A* exports to the sysroot 
will already be there when *B* is built, and the buildtime dependency will be satisfied.

If *B* includes headers exported by *A*, this *is* is a buildtime dependency. But that
does not exclude *B* also having a runtime dependency on *A*. In fact it is usually
the case that if *B* is runtime-dependent on *A* then it is also buildtime-dependent
on *A*, precisely because (for C/C++ packages) the runtime dependency usually 
means that building *B* needs headers from *A*.

If your recipe *only* specifies *B* `RDEPENDS` on *A*, then it needs a tiny bit 
of luck to succeed. If it happened to be the case that *B*'s `do_configure`
included a check for the existence of the *A* headers, *and* all of the
dependencies in play made it possible for *B*'s `do_configure`
to run before *A*'s `do_populate_sysroot` was finished, then that that
check for the *A* headers could fail.

For the recipe to be completely correct and safe, it should specify both
that *B* `RDEPENDS` on *A* *and* that *B* `DEPENDS` on *A*.